# python: I want to realize change point detection using changefinder

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Assumptions**

I am a beginner programmer.

I want to realize change point detection in Python3.
The library used is "ChangeFinder".
I want to get the first-order difference (y_diff) from the temperature data, and output a graph with ChangeFinder applied to it.
Thank you for your answers and advice.

**The problem / error message**

```
ValueError: view limit minimum -36868.78052083334 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

**Applicable source code**

```
import pylab
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa import stattools
from statsmodels.tsa import ar_model
from statsmodels.graphics import tsaplots
import changefinder as cf

df_templeture = pd.read_csv('templeture_data_.csv')
y = pd.Series(df_templeture.templeture.values, index=pd.date_range(start='2019-11-11  22:00:00', periods=len(df_templeture),freq='min'))

y_diff = y.diff()

cf = changefinder.ChangeFinder(r=0.01, order=1, smooth=7)

result = np.empty(len(y_diff))
for i, d in enumerate(y_diff):
    result[i] = cf.update(d)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(result, label="score")
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(y_diff, alpha=0.3, label="observation")
```

**-----Postscript-----**

Graph was displayed. But, score data isn't existed.

**Applicable source code**

```
y_diff = y.diff()
print(y_diff)
data = y_diff.values.tolist()
print(data)
print(len(data))
cf = changefinder.ChangeFinder(r=0.01, order=12, smooth=7)

#y_diff = y.diff().values.tolist()
result = np.empty(len(data))
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    # スコア
    result[i] = cf.update(d)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(ret, label="score")
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(data, alpha=0.3, label="observation")
```

**Result**

```
2019-11-11 22:01:00    0.00
2019-11-11 22:02:00    0.00
2019-11-11 22:03:00    0.00
2019-11-11 22:04:00   -0.49
                       ... 
2019-11-12 21:56:00    0.00
2019-11-12 21:57:00    0.00
2019-11-12 21:58:00    0.00
2019-11-12 21:59:00    0.00
2019-11-12 22:00:00     NaN
Freq: T, Length: 1441, dtype: float64
[nan, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.48999999999999844, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.48999999999999844, -0.48999999999999844, 
・・・
 -0.48999999999999844, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, nan]
1441(←data length)
```

*data length is 1441. But, plot of data display only a few data.*

**The problem / error message**

```
C:\Users\~~~\__init__.py:24: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  lam /= e[k]
C:\Users\~~~\__init__.py:34: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  a = np.array(U) + lam * np.array(V)
C:\Users\~~~\__init__.py:35: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  e[k + 1] = e[k] * (1.0 - lam * lam)
```

I show graph below.

[Graph of "data" and "score"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3VQf.png)

Comment: You'll need to provide the full error stack trace.  And if the error is in `ChangeFinder` it's likely you'll get more help going to [github](https://github.com/shunsukeaihara/changefinder) as it doesn't seem to be a very generally used package.

Comment: Although it seems that `ChangeFinder` works with `numpy` arrays, and `y_diff` is a `pandas.Series`, which is likely the issue.

Comment: @DanielF Thank you! graph was displayed. I converted pd.Series to arrays. Then, next probrem existed. Result plot(Change score) isn't display. Fixed the question. Thank you.

Comment: Cut a bit too much of the file path out of your error trace.  Every package has `__init__.py` so I don't know where to look.  But I'm betting it's `ChangeFinder` which means you'd probably be best asking on that package's github.